# Access swf component from another swf file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Greeting,
I have two flash files myVideo1.swf and myVideo2.swf 
Each one contents FLVPLAYBack  component .
myVideo1.swf  FLVPLAYBack  component instance name is “video1” 
myVideo2.swf  FLVPLAYBack  component instance name is “video2” 
I want to be able to access myVideo2.swf  from myVideo1.swf  using as3.
I want when  I click play button on myVideo2.swf  the myVideo1.swf  would stopped.
Bother flash files are in the same folder.
Please advice how to do this in action script 3 
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First when you load your swf you need to set the loader context domain to your current domain

```
    loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('swf/assets.swf');
    var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
    loader.load(request, context);
```

Then you can access library items set to export using:

```
    var MyClass:Class = Class(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition("export_id"));
    var myInstance:Sprite = new MyClass() as Sprite;
```